# Why does this attempt to create directories fail?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create directories in my python script and it's failing with these 2 errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 91, in create_directories
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(output_files_path,folder))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '..\\..\\output_files\\aws_instance_list\\csv'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 788, in <module>
    main()
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 579, in main
    create_directories()
  File ".\aws_ec2_list_instances.py", line 93, in create_directories
    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
NameError: name 'errno' is not defined
```

This is my code:

```
def create_directories():

    ## Set source and output file directories
    source_files_path = os.path.join('..', '..', 'source_files', 'aws_accounts_list')
    output_files_path = os.path.join('..', '..', 'output_files', 'aws_instance_list')

    # Create source files directory
    try:
        os.makedirs('source_files_path')
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise

    # Create output directories
    folders = ['csv','excel','html', 'json']
    for folder in folders:
        try:
            os.mkdir(os.path.join(output_files_path,folder))
        except OSError as e:
            if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
                raise
```

Why does it fail to create the `output_files\aws_instance_list` directory and why does it fail when I try to capture the error in `if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:`?

Comment: Concerning `errno`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62222575/python-continue-with-execution-in-case-of-exception

Comment: You meant `os.makedirs(source_files_path)` without quotes - your code just created a directory with this litteral name. So it's not a duplicate of anything, it's a typo.

Comment: `os.mkdir(os.path.join(output_files_path,folder))` This will only make the final `folder` directory; `output_files_path` must already exist.  Does it?

Comment: No it doesn't. I thought this command would create both directories.

Comment: `makedirs()` does that, but you're calling `mkdir()`.

Comment: It would have existed (or the first part of the code would have raised an error) without the typo, as `source_files_path` and `output_files_path` are defined as the same directory.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille What?  No they are not the same.  One has `'source_files'` and the other has `'output_files'`.

Comment: Oh, , you're right, thanks... And I  had checked a few times. My poor eyes... :/